# HDF5 dataset stores nothing but 0/empty values

Tags: python, csv, hdf5, h5py, word-embedding

I am writing a CSV file into an HDF5 file to load information in a better way without filling up the memory. My CSV file contains indices that I am converting to their corresponding values through a dictionary.

The CSV file is very big (4 GB worth of indices) and the corresponding values are `512` sized arrays. To create the dataset, I first define the datasets in the H5 file, and then chunk-wise read the CSV file so that it uses an appropriate amount of RAM

```
num_lines = 1000000
chunksize = 100000
num_features = 512

with h5py.File('./data/dataset.h5', 'w') as h5f:

    # use num_features-1 if the csv file has a column header
    dset1 = h5f.create_dataset('paragraph_embeddings',
                               shape=(num_lines, num_features),
                               compression=None,
                               dtype='float32')
    dset2 = h5f.create_dataset('sentence_embeddings',
                               shape=(num_lines, num_features),
                               compression=None,
                               dtype='float32')
    dset3 = h5f.create_dataset('labels',
                               shape=(num_lines,),
                               compression=None,
                               dtype='int32')

    # Read csv in chunks so that RAM does not overflow
    for i in range(0, num_lines, chunksize):

        df = pd.read_csv(csv_path,
                header=None,
                nrows=chunksize, # number of rows to read at each iteration
                skiprows=i)   # skip rows that were already read
        df.columns = ["para_index", "sentence_index", "label"]

        # Get embeddings from dictionaries (para_mappings and sentence_mappings)
        paragraph_embeddings = df["para_index"].map(para_mappings)
        sentence_embeddings = df["sentence_index"].astype(str).map(sentence_mappings)
        label = df["label"]

        # Append to the datasets
        dset1[i:i+chunksize, num_features:] = paragraph_embeddings
        dset2[i:i+chunksize, num_features:] = sentence_embeddings
        dset3[i:i+chunksize] = label
```

I map the indices to their corresponding values using the `df.map` function. After that, I get the embedding (or the `512` sized arrays as I described earlier). After that, I append them to their corresponding datasets.

However, to test, I print an embedding from the H5 file, using this:

```
with h5py.File('./data/dataset.h5', 'r') as h5f:
    print('Embedding', h5f['paragraph_embeddings'][2])
```

And I get an array of zeros (of size `512`) as an output.

Can anyone guide me where I am going wrong here? As per my estimate, it should be where I am "appending" the embedding to the datasets. In my opinion, I am not appending the values and doing something wrong there.

Also, when I test the labels, they are coming out to be correct. So, I guess, it mainly highlights my issue to this line:

`dset1[i:i+chunksize, num_features:] = paragraph_embeddings`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in this line:

```
paragraph_embeddings = df["para_index"].map(para_mappings)
```

It was giving me a data frame of the chunk-size, with each element being a numpy array (of size 512). When I was writing it into the dataset it was not accepting when I put in the data as:

```
dset1[i:i+chunksize] = paragraph_embeddings
```

It gave me an error saying that it cannot enter data of size `chunk-size` into the dataset of size `[chunk-size, 512]`. This gave me a clue to convert the dataframe to a numpy array of shape `[chunk-size, 512]` first and then add it to the dataset. Which worked, as expected.

```
paragraph_embeddings = np.array(df["para_index"].map(para_mappings).tolist())
```